# How to understand is_callable definition?

Tags: c++, c++17

In draft of the ISO C++ standard specification N4606, in §20.15.6, `is_callable` is defined as this:

> ```
> template <class Fn, class...ArgTypes, class R>
> struct is_callable<Fn(ArgTypes...), R>
> ```
>
> The expression `INVOKE(declval<Fn>(),declval<ArgTypes>()...,R)` is well formed when treated as an unevaluated operand.

As far as I understand `Fn(ArgTypes...)` is the signature of a function returning an `Fn` and taking as arguments `ArgTypes...`.

So `INVOKE(declval<Fn>(),...)` will try to call the return value of the function??

So what is the goal of `is_callable`? Or where do I get wrong?

Comment: What's `INVOKE`, by the way? I see it mentioned in the C++ reference, but can't find the definition.

Comment: I think an idea behind `std::is_callable` first parameter is similar to [`std::result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) parameter

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I've seen that. What `INVOKE`, capital case?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: Actually read the page.

Comment: _"where INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN) is defined as follows:"_ on the **second** line...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'm a programmer, not a reader, don't be so hard on me :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my understanding `std::is_callable` will answer the question if an instance of `Fn` can be called with instances of `ArgTypes...` as parameters and if this call will result in an object of `R` type.

To give you an example:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
    int operator()(int, float, double) { return 0; }
};

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_callable<A(int, float, double), int>::value, "!");
    static_assert(!std::is_callable<A(int, int), int>::value, "!!");
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1qtGCiWDfV07QbKM)